# Persistent overuse of system resources by rust-analyzer

Tags: rust, compilation

After limiting the number jobs in order to handle the amount of resources used by rust-analyzer it keeps using all cores so my computer ends up hanged out:

[image]

In addition, I've noticed that several processes continue to run even after stopping the rust-analyzer. Notably, it's these processes that are consuming all available cores:

```
...
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/cc1plus -quite -I /home/c/rust-project/target/debug/build/wasm-opt-sys...
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/cc1plus -quite -I rocksdb/include/ -I rocksdb/ -I rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/ -I snappy...
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/cc1plus -quite -I rocksdb/include/ -I rocksdb/ -I rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/ -I snappy...
...
```

For reference, my laptop is equipped with 16 cores and has 16GB RAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've realized that the more appropriate parameter for setting the number of jobs is "**cargo**.extraArgs", rather than "**check**.extraArgs". As of now, no cargo command will use more than the specified number of jobs.

[image]